# Defining table structure for a database?

Tags: sql, database, linux, database-design

Up until now, my experience with databases has always been working with an intermediate definition layer that we have where I work.  i.e. SQL wasn't directly written for the table definitions, but generated from an intermediate file which wrote out SQL scripts for creating the appropriate tables, upgrade scripts between schema changes, and helper functions for doing simple queries/updates/inserts/deletes from the database.

Now I'm in a situation where I don't have access to that, for reasons I won't get into, and I find myself somewhat lost at sea regarding what to do.  I need to have a small number of tables in a database, and I'm unsure what's usually done to manage the table definitions.

Do people normally just use the SQL script that does the table creation as their definition, or does everyone just use an IDE that manages the definition in a separate file and regenerates the SQL script to create the tables?

I'd really prefer not to have to introduce a dependence on a specific IDE, because as we all know, developers are whiners that are prone to religious debates over small things.

Comment: Most places i've worked have put the schema DDL in one or more files

Comment: " because as we all know, developers are whiners that are prone to religious debates over small things."  We all know that because this is a place where questions are mostly asked and answered by developers....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open your favorite text editor -> Start writing CREATE scripts -> Save -> Put in Source Control

That script now becomes the basis for you database. Anytime there are schema changes, they get put back into the scripts so that they don't get lost.

These become your definition.

I find it more reliable than depending on any specific IDE/Platform generating those scripts for you.

Comment: +1 As a famous philosopher once said, "It's easy to do, just follow these steps."

Comment: +1 for source control.  It is depressing how few places protect their DDL scripts

Comment: Thanks.  Guess I'll start writing my create scripts then.

Answer (score 1):

We write the scripts ourselves and store them in source control like any other code. Then the scripts that are appropriate for a particular version are all groupd together and promoted to prod together. Make sure to use alter table when changing existing tables becasue you don't want to drop and recreate them if they have data! I use a drop and recireate for all other objects though. If you need to add records to a particular table (usually a lookup of sometype) we do that in scripts as well. Then that too gets promoted with the rest of the version code.

For me, putting the scripts in source control however they are generated is the key step. This is how you know what you have changed for the next release. This is how you can see earlier versions and revert back easily if there is a problem. Treat database code the same wayyou treat all other code.

Answer (score 1):

YOu could use one of the data modelling tools that creates scripts for you if you are starting out on a database design and the eventually want to create it for you. Some tools for that are Erwin, Fabforce etc... (though not free)

If you have access to an IDE like SQL Management studio, you can create them by using an GUI thats pretty simple.

If you are writing your own code, Its always better to write your own scripts based on a good template so that you cover all the properties of the definition of the table like the file_group, Collation & stuff. Hope this helps

Once you do create a base copy generate scripts and have a base reference copy of it so that you could do "incremental" changes on them and manage them in a source control.

Answer (score 0):

Though I use TOAD for Oracle, I always write the scripts to create my database objects by hand. It gives you (and your DBA's) more control and knowledge of what's being created and how.

Answer (score 0):

If your schema is too difficult to describe in SQL, you probably have other issues more pressing than which IDE. Use modelling **documentation** if you need a graphical representation, but yeah, you don't need an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways out there for what you are asking.
Old traditional way is to have a script file ready with your application that has `CREATE TABLE` statement.

If you are a developer, and that too a Java enterprise developer, you could generate complete schema using a persistence library called Hibernate. [Here is a how to](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2008/jw-08-hibernate-annotations.html)

If you are a DBA level user, you could take schema export from one environment and import that in to your current environment. This is a standard practice among DBAs. But it requires admin access as you can see. Also, the methods are dependent on the database you are using (oracle, db2 etc)